# Drupal View for the 10 Most Recent Items Sorted by Date ASC

Tags: views

Is it possible to construct a view of the 10 most recent nodes sorted by date in ascending order?

This sounds simple, but it seems as if it's more complicated than I'd imagined.

I think to do this in SQL you'd need a subquery, and I can't see that views is capable of that...

...or is it possible to reverse the order of the rows in the view after they're brought back from the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like a problem with sorting and offset.

To get the **10 most recent** nodes sorted by **date descending** is easy and will return the correct result. You are however sorting for the **10 most recent** by **date ascending** and will just get the **10 oldest** nodes.

Ideally you need to get the count of all nodes as by your criteria, then subtract 10 from that to use as the offset.

The easiest is to just **reverse the order before rendering**. Construct your view to sort by **date descending**, then add this to your theme's `template.php` file:

```
function THEME_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == "VIEWNAME" && $view->current_display == "DISPLAYNAME") {
    $view->result = array_reverse($view->result);
  }
}
```

After you add this code you need to clear your cache.

You get the view machine name and display name like this:

[image]

Hover mouse on View tab, then look at link below: here `most_recent` is the view machine name and `page` is the display name.

Comment: I managed to create a custom module which creates a custom views display extender that puts in an option called "Reverse Results" under the "Advanced->Other" section in the Views UI. I implemented hook_views_post_execute so that any views format should get the results in reverse. Thanks for your help!